# tsConfig not resolving "@/*" paths

Tags: vue.js, path, vite, tsconfig

I'm trying to make a path alias for "./src/components" which works in Vite but not in tsConfig file. I have tried all solutions on Stackoverflow but with no avail.

**tsConfig.js**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    },
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

**project tree**

[image]

**Error Message**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you must do it like this:

```
import TextInput from "@/components/core/TextInput.vue"
```

you are misssed / after @

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was supposed to be like that "@components" as configured in tsConfig.ts

Answer (score 0):

The paths must `"@components/*": ["src/components/*"]` as your components folder is inside src

And You have to update your vite.config.ts file respectively

Comment: Thanks for the reply! in my tsConfig.ts, the "baseUrl" is set to "./src" already. So I don't need to specify the src folder in "paths".

Comment: Is your TextInput.vue inside core folder?

Comment: Yes, it is inside the code folder.